# How to derive the following flooring function?

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

I am a programmer and for avoiding floating point precision problem in computing, I found somewhere on the internet the following is the same:

$\lceil\frac{a}{b}\rceil$ = $\lfloor\frac{a+b-1}{b}\rfloor$

While it gives correct results (based on testing), I always forgot this handy formula. So I want to learn the way of deriving this result.

Assuming both $a, b$ are integers. $b > 0$

*How can one derive R.H.S. from L.H.S.?*

Comment: $\lceil a/b \rceil =n$ means $n-1 <a/b \le n $ so $nb -b < a \le bn; nb <a +b \le nb+ b; n < (a+b)/b \le n+1; n-1/b < (a+b-1)/b \le n + 1 - 1/b < n+1$.  So $\lfloor (a+b-1)/b\rfloor = n|n-1$...well, that's a start...

Comment: It does not hold for $a=1,b=-1$. Are you assuming that $b$ is positive?

Comment: @mathlove yes, sorry for not mentioning that, edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is first observe that: $$\left\lfloor{\frac{a+b-1}{b}}\right\rfloor = \left\lfloor{\frac{a-1}{b}+1}\right\rfloor = \left\lfloor{\frac{a-1}{b}}\right\rfloor + 1$$ since integers can always be "pulled out" of floor/ceiling functions. Thus, the identity to be proved is equivalent to: $$\left\lceil{\frac{a}{b}}\right\rceil = \left\lfloor{\frac{a-1}{b}}\right\rfloor + 1$$

Now, let $q$ and $r$ be the quotient and remainder of the division of $a-1$ by $b$ so that $$a - 1 = q b + r \;\;\; \text{ with } \; 0 \le r \lt b$$

Then:

$$
\frac{a}{b} = q + \frac{r+1}{b} \;\;\; \text{ where } \;0 \lt \frac{r+1}{b} \le 1 \;\;\; \text{ so } \;\left\lceil{\frac{a}{b}}\right\rceil = q + 1
$$

and:

$$
\frac{a-1}{b} = q + \frac{r}{b} \;\;\; \text{ where } \;0 \le \frac{r}{b} \lt 1 \;\;\; \text{ so } \;\left\lfloor{\frac{a-1}{b}}\right\rfloor = q
$$

from which the sought equality follows.